# ¿Cómo insertar datos a una BD desde un textarea?

Tags: php, mysql

Espero puedan ayudarme. Tengo un formulario en `PHP` con con un `textarea` y cuando ingreso un contenido....

EJEMPLO:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.
>
> Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Me lo sube a la base de datos, todo en un párrafo.

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

Hay forma que me distinga los saltos de línea?

Eso se hace en la programación o se asigna algún tipo de datos en la base de datos?

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, podrías mostrarnos tu código php?. Es muy probable que el contenido del `textarea` se este enviando como texto plano. Para que respete párrafos y saltos de linea debe ir con formato html (con el apoyo de etiquetas `<p>`y `<br>`. Una manera simple de solucionar esto es implementar algún editor de texto enriquecido que mejore tu textarea (te sugiero revisar [summernote](https://summernote.org)) .

Comment: Como te dice @RicardoCamposVillarroel implemente algún editor de texto, por ejemplo CKEditor https://ckeditor.com/

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: PD. Las mayúsculas sostenidas son innecesarias. Se asume que estás gritando y pues, no veo que sea la idea en tu caso.

Comment: Ricardo Campos Villarroel. Lo estuve insertando como texto plano. Con un INSERT INTO y editor de texto sugerido me fue de mucha utilidad Pavlo B. GRACIAS A AMBOS

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizando esta funcion de php para mostrar el texto

`nl2br ( $text)`

o quiza te ayude este estilo de CSS en el contenedor del texto que guardaste

`white-space: pre-line`